# Parsing JSON response from Twitter Search API not working using PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, twitter

I am using the Twitter Search API 1.1 to search for tweets on a particular keyword and display the results as a search results page at motherpipe.co.uk.

I have managed to get the Oauth working with the help of James Mallison at http://github.com/j7mbo/twitter-api-php.

I am stuck at the stage of taking the actual response I get from Twitter and display it normally in divs in HTML (using PHP). This is the reply I get: https://motherpipe.co.uk/staging/index2.php.

I just can't seem to write a simple loop to display only the 'screen_name' and 'text'.

So far I have tried different versions of this:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$getfield = '?q=sweden&result_type=recent';


$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter ->setGetfield($getfield)
                ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
               ->performRequest();


$response = json_decode($twitter);

foreach($response as $tweet)
{
  echo "{$tweet->screen_name} {$tweet->text}\n";
}
```

Any feedback or ideas on how to loop through this correctly would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: you're not showing us your whole code. `Notice: Undefined variable: objJson in /var/www/vhosts/motherpipe.co.uk/httpdocs/staging/index2.php on line 27`

Comment: Yes sorry I was trying to do a loop after the actual printout of the response from twitter. Live at that page after the actual content of the Twitter response is 

$data = array();
foreach($objJson["statuses"] as $status) {
    $data[] = array(
        "created_at" => $status["created_at"],
        "text" => $status["text"]
    );
}
echo "<pre>" . print_r($data,1) . "</pre>";
?>

Comment: you can find a working api at the footer of this page.[Twitter ApiV1.1](http://tweetsdecoder.com) If you want something like this or further customisation let me know

Answer (score 2):

I dont use james code but I get it working other way round

```
<ul>
<?php $get_tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

foreach($get_tweets as $tweet) { 

$tweet_desc = $tweet->text;
?>

<li><?php echo $tweet_desc ?></li>

<?php }?>
</ul>
```

You can see a working Twitter Api V1.1 at the footer of [this page.](http://tweetsdecoder.net) If you want something like this or further customisation let me know .

Answer (score 1):

If you would do a `var_dump` of `$response`, you would probably get a better idea of the structure. Looks like you need to loop over `$response->statuses`. The user information is under `$tweet->user->screen_name` and the tweet text is under `$tweet->text`. So:

```
$response = json_decode($twitter);

foreach($response->statuses as $tweet)
{
  echo "{$tweet->user->screen_name} {$tweet->text}\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I tried your suggestion but am getting 2 errors. "Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string" , and "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()".

Answer (score 1):

The user information is under `$tweet->user->screen_name` and the tweet text is under `$tweet->text`

```
$response = json_decode($twitter);

foreach($response->statuses as $tweet)
{
  echo "{$tweet->user->screen_name} {$tweet->text}<br />";
}
```

OR also you can use this too

```
$response = json_decode($twitter, true);
$counter = 0;
foreach($response['statuses'] as $tweet)
{
  echo "{$tweet[$counter]['user']['screen_name'] {$tweet[$counter]['text']}<br />";
  $counter +=1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the answer (thanks to Prisoner, Jonathan Kuhn and Mubin Khalid) is, in order to display the response from  the Twitter Search API, assign a variable to the Twitter JSON response. This will enable you to loop through and display whatever you want from the response.

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$getfield = '?q=sweden&result_type=recent';


$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

$api_response = $twitter ->setGetfield($getfield)
                     ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                     ->performRequest();


$response = json_decode($api_response);

foreach($response->statuses as $tweet)
{
  echo "{$tweet->user->screen_name} {$tweet->text}\n";
}
```